# AudioSegment results in MemoryError while i have plenty of memory

Tags: python, pydub, audiosegment

I'm trying to concatenate two mp3 files with AudioSegment (pydub). For small size files (less then 35 Mb) it's working. For bigger, i get a MemoryError.
Python version:3.6.2

Here is my code. Thank you for any help!

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import eyed3
import os
import gc
import psutil

def make_files(path_to_files, audiofiles):
    pre_sermon = AudioSegment.from_mp3("pre_sermon.mp3")
    for file_name in audiofiles:     
        sermon = AudioSegment.from_mp3(path_to_files + file_name)      
        combined = pre_sermon + sermon

        audiofile = eyed3.load(path_to_files + file_name)
        combined.export(f'combined/{file_name}', format="mp3", bitrate='128k', tags={'title': audiofile.tag.title, 
                                                                                     'artist': audiofile.tag.artist, 
                                                                                     'album': audiofile.tag.album, 
                                                                                     'comment': audiofile.tag.comments[0].text})

        del combined
        del sermon
        gc.collect()

general_path = 'C:\\projects\\python\\files\\mp3\\sermons\\'
files = set(os.listdir('sermons/'))
combined_files = set(os.listdir('combined/'))
difference = {filename:str(os.stat(os.path.join(general_path, filename)).st_size/1000000) + ' MB' for filename in (files - combined_files)}

print(psutil.virtual_memory())
print(difference)
make_files('sermons/', difference.keys())
```

[printscreen of error and additional info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzdBC.jpg)

Comment: Are you using a 32-bit python interpreter or 64-bit python interpreter?

Comment: 32-bit interpreter. I will try use 64-bit.

Comment: that was the problem! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

the problem was solved with a 64-bit python interpreter. Thank you Jiaaro!